# Создание виджета

Tags: php, wordpress, виджет

Хочу добавить новые виджеты к уже имеющимя в WP виджетам.
Нужно два виджета:
Виджет для вывода последних постов с миниатюрой и цитатой поста;
Виджет для вывода небольшой новости с картинкой.
Решил создать эти виджеты на основе имеющихся в WP виджетов, это виджеты вывода последних постов и текстовый виджет. Получилось сделать так, что бы виджет последних постов выводил не только название постов, но и их миниатюры и цитату. Хочу сделать так, что бы пользователь сам мог задать длину цитаты. Получилось создать текстовое поле с значением длины цитаты по умолчание. Так вот, проблема заключается в том что когда я ввожу другое число, отличное от числа которое стоит по умолчанию, то оно меняется, но когда я пытаюсь сохранить внесенные изменения, то цифра опять становиться по умолчанию.
Вот внешний вид виджета:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код виджета:

```
<?php

class My_Recent_Posts extends WP_Widget {

public function __construct() {
    $widget_ops = array(
        'description' => "Последние записи с миниатюрой и цитатой."
    );
    parent::__construct( 'recent-posts', 'Последние записи с миниатюрой', $widget_ops );
    $this->alt_option_name = 'widget_recent_entries';
}

// Отоброжение виджета на сайте
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    if ( !isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
        $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
    }

    $title = (!empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : '';

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

    $number = (!empty( $instance['number'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
    if ( !$number )
        $number = 5;
    $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? $instance['show_date'] : false;
    // Длина поста
    $post_length = (!empty( $instance['post_length'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['post_length'] ) : 200;

    // Выбор последних постов
    $r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
                'posts_per_page' => $number,
                'no_found_rows' => true,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
            ) ) );

    if ( $r->have_posts() ) :
        ?>
        <?php echo $args['before_widget']; ?>
        <?php
        if ( $title ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }
        ?>
        <ul class="divided">
            <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <article class="box highlight">
                        <header>
                            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a></h3>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="image left"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'strongly-min' ); ?></a>
                            <p><?php
                                // Вывод поста
                                echo mb_substr( strip_tags( get_the_content() ), 0, $post_length );
                                ?>
                            </p>
                            <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
                                <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
                            <ul class="actions">
                                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button icon fa-file">Читать далее...</a></li>
                            </ul>

                    </article>
                </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php echo $args['after_widget']; ?>
        <?php
        // Reset the global $the_post as this query will have stomped on it
        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
}

// Обновление данных
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );
    $instance['number'] = (int) $new_instance['number'];
    // Обновление значения длины поста
    $instance['post_length'] = (int) $new_instance['post_length'];
    $instance['show_date'] = isset( $new_instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $new_instance['show_date'] : false;
    return $instance;
}

// Отображение виджета в админке
public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
    $number = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
    $post_length = isset( $instance['post_length'] ) ? absint( $instance['post_length'] ) : 200;
    $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $instance['show_date'] : false;
    ?>
    <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></p>

    <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="tiny-text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="1" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" /></p>

    <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"<?php checked( $show_date ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_date' ); ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Display post date?' ); ?></label></p>

    <!--Текстовое поле для ввода длины поста-->
    <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_length' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Длина поста:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_length' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'post_length' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="1" value="<?php echo $post_length; ?>" size="3" /></p>
    <?php
}

}

function top_posts_widget() {
   register_widget( 'My_Recent_Posts' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'top_posts_widget' );
```

Как быть и что делать? В чем ошибка? Подскажите пожалуйста.

На счет второго виджета.
Как добавить к текстовому виджету кнопку, которая будет открывать окошко выбора медиафайла из библиотеки WP? Хочу добавлять небольшие новости/заметки с картинкой. На сайте что бы выводилось почти также как и последние записи с миниатюрой и цитатой, только без кнопки "Читать далее..."